# Audio RMS normalization prior to a DNN classification

Tags: audio-processing, normalization, deep-learning

I want to normalize my data prior to a deep neural network model (DNN). It was recommended to me to use real mean square (RMS) normalization for audio, though I am not sure this is the best for a DNN. I am using MFCC features to represent the data.

Is RMS a good method? If so, how do I choose a good RMS value to normalize with respect to that value? Is there a rule of thumb?

Comment: Are you planning on using 0'th MFCC coefficient (energy)?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I am using the lowest MFCC line (was that what you were referring to?)

Comment: You will calculate certain number of coefficients for each frame of audio (be it 13, 16, etc). Are you gonna use them all? The 0'th coefficient (depending on implementation) will be the energy of all log-mel energies.

Comment: I am using MFCC with 40 coefficients and I am using all of them.